# How to trigger iPhone zoom-out after auto zoom-in to a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jquery-events

I have a web form that uses jQuery to submit a search. The form itself doesn't fire the submit event because I catch that and drop it (this is all part of a much larger and more complex form and I'm using progressive enhancement to add this functionality).

On the iPhone, the browser automatically zooms in to my search input as soon as it is focused. On an "enter" keyup event, the search is executed via javascript, and I blur the input which dismisses the on screen iPhone keyboard, but the browser stays zoomed in to the input area.

Is there a way to programatically trigger zooming out again back to the initial viewport area via javascript?

EDIT: there's no redirect on search execution which would normally reset the viewport when the new page loads - everything happens on one page here.

Comment: There seems to be several solutions. Check the url below:-

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310074/disable-input-auto-zooming-on-mobile-devices

Answer (score 42):

If the input's font-size is a minimum of 16px the zoom in will not be triggered to begin with.

Comment: that's really helpful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This feels like much better practice than Javascripting your way out of this paper bag.

Comment: This is the way to solve the problem - works along with `width=device-width,initial-scale=1` without needing `maximum-scale`.

Answer (score 10):

Do you need or want to allow people to zoom at all? If not, have you set this meta tag in your head?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

As far as I'm aware, that will stop the zoom issue in the first instance.

Comment: This is an incredibly bad idea if you care about accessibility.

Comment: It's not bad for accessibility in and of itself. It's bad for accessibility if you misuse this where you don't need to. In some instances this is a very useful and important feature. In any case, I don't think you can prevent zoom in iOS any longer.

Comment: I have to disagree. As a user I don't want to be restricted by max scale level should I need to zoom for better text legibility. This meta completely disables that ability. This topic has been discussed 1000 times on the internet and the general consensus is to not disable scaling. Apple have also disabled this meta tag in iOS10 — https://medium.com/@johan_ronsse/re-apple-disabling-maximum-scale-behavior-on-responsive-websites-in-ios10-17bc7b0f27c0

Comment: Apple will disregard maximum-scale and user-scalable sind iOS10
So even it this solution would be a11l friendly - it wont work any more.

https://medium.com/@johan_ronsse/re-apple-disabling-maximum-scale-behavior-on-responsive-websites-in-ios10-17bc7b0f27c0

Comment: Yes, 99% of the time people should be able to zoom but imagine you had a web game that had complex gestures. I could imagine it being frustrating or necessitate a need for verbose JavaScript to get around it. That’s not good for anybody. Anyhow, it’s pointless if Apple are removing it but just wanted to add my reasoning as to why it may not always be “bad”.

Answer (score 9):

I've used the following successfully.

```js
$('input, select, textarea').on('focus blur', function(event) {
    $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=' + (event.type == 'blur' ? 10 : 1));
  });

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Type here..." />
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. It feels horrible that we even have to do this... Why would a user want to remain zoomed in after filling out an input?!

Comment: Doesn't this leave in the new viewport after an input is clicked? If that's the approach, why not just use that viewport to start with?

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, won't this prevent zoom in on the next input entered?

Comment: no, because it sets the zoom to 10 on 'focus' events. that's why she checks the event type with a ternary statement before assigning the zoom level.

Comment: This did not work for me on Mobile Safari 14

Answer (score 3):

.css

```
input[type=search] {
    font-size: max(1em, 16px);
}
```

as mentioned in other answers, using the 16px font size

1. prevents the browser from zooming in the first place
2. avoids using maximum-scale in the meta tag which prevents zooming in other
   browsers

Answer (score 1):

the focus and blur event above did not work for me,
to ensure that safari zooms out on blur and that it resets the "maximum-scale" to 10 afterwards I did this:

the function needs to be called on both blur and focus events, as the onFocus event will clear the timeout. This is in case the user goes directly from one input field into another.

```
let iosZoom10Timer: any = null;
let iosZoom1Timer: any = null;
function handleZoomOnIOS(e) {

    if (e.type === 'blur') {
        iosZoom1Timer = setTimeout(
            function () {
                document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1');

                iosZoom10Timer = setTimeout(
                    function () {
                        document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=10');
                    }, 100);
            }, 100);

    }
    else if (e.type === 'focus') {
        clearTimeout(iosZoom1Timer);
    }
}
```