# Disable input auto-zooming on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile

The issue is mobile browsers will zoom in an input field or select drop-down on focus. I've looked into different solutions and so far the most elegant I found does it with setting a font-size of an input field to 16px. This works fine on a standalone input field but if you have a parent container which incorporates a button, after changing font-size to 16px will make a bit of a gap under the button.

Another solution would be to set a default font-size for input fields to 16px and adjust a button size correctly.

Setting a font-size to 16px doesn't prevent select drop-downs from zooming though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472891/how-can-i-disable-zoom-on-a-mobile-web-page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154505/how-can-i-force-a-site-to-scale-to-fix-for-mobile-iphone-android @MarcellFülöp beat me to it...

Comment: I think we shouldn't fully restrict mobile users from zooming in. Otherwise this solution would be ideal. The idea is to prevent from zooming on input fields and select drop-downs only.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```